# Spring Boot lookup for Log4J2 does not work

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

The Log4J2 documentation describes a collection of "lookups" (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#) that can be used to provide dynamic information to Log4J2 configuration. One of these is labeled "Spring lookup" which supposedly allows for Log4J2 configuration properties to be used from Spring Boot configuration:

> Spring Boot Lookup
>
> The Spring Boot Lookup retrieves the values of Spring properties from the Spring configuration. This Lookup will return null values until Spring Boot initializes application logging.

```
<File name="Application" fileName="application.log">
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] $${spring:spring.application.name} %m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
</File>
```

> This Lookup requires log4j-spring-cloud-config-client be included in the application.

I had originally missed the requirement for `log4j-spring-cloud-config-client` so not surprised it did not work the first time around.

So, I then added the dependency for the spring cloud client and tried again.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now the application throws an exception when started:

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE:start (pre-integration-test) @ mission-planner ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:78)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:60)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:155)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:194)
        at edu.mit.ll.mission_services.service.mission_planner.ApplicationMain.main(ApplicationMain.java:53)
```

Comment: Are all the log4j jars at version 2.13.0?